# how to set the name of a variable on creation dynamically the same as the name/ property of another field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some documents with key / value pairs, now, I would like to create a second document, that has as its  identifier (or self property) the name of some property of that second document.

Example:
Original Document:

```
Country = {
code: "ger",
lang: "de",
someArr: [...]
}
```

now, I would like to create a second document with a certain format so I can fit it in a chart (e.g ngx charts):

```
var ger = {lang: "de",...}
```

as you can see, that document has its variable name (var "ger") the name of the Country code, is it possible to pass dynamically the name of the Country code field as variable name for all documents? So if I have different countries in the array of documents, each time when I loop through it, I generate another document with its variable name the same as that document country code?

or would I have to create only anonymous documents with index fields and set the country code as a key field only?

Comment: You don't do that. Variable names are static. If you need it to be dynamic, don't use a variable.

Comment: Why does the name matter? Why would you call it `foo` instead of `bar` in some cases ? Why not just go with one?

Comment: What type of documents? Do you mean you are generating js files? If so you have access to keys and values of your objects so there should be no issue i.e `for(key in obj):`

Comment: well the reason is, I have to create "const fieldname = { name:... value:...}, so for each data object from httpRequest, I need to create a corresponding data format for that field, with name, value inside a document. I Would like to give the document a variable that has a "speaking name" itself, instead of var1, var2 the thing is, I don't know in advance how many objects / fields my data has and how many documents I have to create in advance, so it would be much easier, if I could just give the docs the names of the data fields, and just retrieve the corresponding docs by their field names...

Comment: @user2883596 The point is, when you don't know how many documents you will have then you cannot use a variable per document, as variables need to be known beforehand. Use a collection (array, object, `Map` etc) instead.

Comment: yeah, but I want to loop (or map) foreach array element over the fields, and then just create a dok for each field and the name of the doc corresponding to the field name, so I can just return all the corresponding fields by their name that I want (and I can choose freely). I cannot do this if I have to do dict1, dict2... or whatever..